# How are (95%) confidence intervals for beta distribution parameters calculated, and can they be used to derive confidence intervals for the mean?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, maximum-likelihood, beta-distribution

Closely related to: [Calculate the confidence interval for the mean of a beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82475/calculate-the-confidence-interval-for-the-mean-of-a-beta-distribution)

I am fitting a a $\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$ distribution to some data using Matlab's `betafit` function which has produced confidence intervals for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I am wondering whether it is possible to derive confidence intervals for the implied mean parameter $\mu = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}$ from these.

Note that my question is different to the one I linked previously as that one explicitly relies on parametrizing the Beta log-likelihood function in terms of $\mu$ and the nuisance parameter $\sigma$, and then calculates the CI for $\mu$ using profile likelihood.

In addition, I do not understand the [Matlab documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/betafit.html) when it says:

> The confidence intervals are based on a normal approximation for the distribution of the logs of the parameter estimates.

What distribution does the log of the parameter estimates take?

Comment: This question requires the self study tag.

Comment: don't see why it should have a self study tag as it is not "A routine question from a textbook, course, or test used for a class or self-study."

Comment: You just explained why it does need the self study tag.

Comment: Please point me to where this is a routine question and I will look up the relevant resource and see whether I can solve it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the document, Matlab estimates the parameters for Beta distribution with the maximum likelihood. In this case, I am afraid that the sampling distributions for the estimators are not available. Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a set of i.i.d. observations from standard Beta distribution $B(\alpha,\beta)$, obtaining the MLEs $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ requires one to solve simultaneous equations \begin{align}\psi(\hat{\alpha})-\psi(\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta})&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln (X_i),\\\psi(\hat{\beta})-\psi(\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta})&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln (1-X_i),\end{align} where $\psi$ denotes the digamma function (see e.g. Gnanadesikan, Pinkham, and Hughes' *[Maximum Likelihood Estimation of the Parameters of the Beta Distribution from Smallest Order Statistics](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1266199)* for more details). As far as I know, no general analytical solutions are available, let alone the exact distributions of $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$. It is possible to solve them in special cases however, e.g. when $\beta$ are known to be exactly $1$, by properties of digamma function the first equation can be reduced to $$\hat{\alpha}=-\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\ln (X_i)},$$ where one can derive that $-\sum_{i=1}^n\ln (X_i)\sim\varGamma(n,1/\alpha)$, which implies $\hat{\alpha}$ has scaled [inverse-Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution). Other than that, one has to resort to the asymptotic normality of MLEs to make inferences on $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$, also see e.g. Lau and Lau's [*Effective procedures for estimating beta
distribution's parameters and Their confidence
intervals*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00949659108811325) for procedure using [Pearson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution). In addition, one may utilize the normality to derive confidence intervals for the mean, since $$\hat{\mu}=\frac{\hat{\alpha}}{\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}}$$ will have [correlated normal ratio distribution](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2334671) if both $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are normal.

For your second question, I take that logs of estimates are used most likely to cope with the problem of parameter space. Note that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must be in $(0,\infty)$. But if your $\hat{\alpha}=1$ and you use normal approximation directly, you may end up with confidence interval such as $(-0.5,2.5)$. You can get around this by mapping to log-scale and then back, though I am not sure how accurate the result will be then.

As an interesting side note, the book (Hahn and Shapiro's *Statistical Models in Engineering*) cited in the documentation actually talked about method of moments estimate instead of MLE, it is not clear to me why it is cited here.

Comment: thanks for the detailed analysis of each part of my question.